# How to make simple button navigation in ionic with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm making a functional button in my ionic app, and I want to know what I need to do to make a button centered on a blank ionic app load another page when clicked.

I have experimented with adding `ng-click="loadPage()"` to the button in my index.html file. I defined 
`$scope.loadPage = function() { $state.go(page.html)}` in my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

switch your button with an anchor

```
<a class="btn btn-full" ui-sref="your.state">your text</a>
```